# Debug Doesn’t Work After Migrating SmartGWT from v4.0 to v13.0

Tags: java, smartgwt, isomorphic-javascript, smartgwt-pro, gwt-2.8

I have a test environment with the BuiltInDs project that uses the following components:
JDK 1.8
SmartGWT Eval v13.0-p20221103
GWT 2.8.2
Maven 3.8.6

And to run it I use the following targets:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

With this configuration, I can access Developer Mode for debugging the code and it works correctly.

On the other hand, I have an environment with a real project that uses the following components:
JDK 1.8
SmartGWT Pro v4.0
GWT 2.8.0
Maven 2.0

And I run it using the following goals:
[[image]
[image]

With those goals I can access the Developer Mode for debugging the code and it works correctly.

Now, when I migrate the productive project to the SmartGWT v13.0-p20221103 version with GWT 2.8.2, the same Maven 2.0 and JDK 1.8, with the same goals that worked in the project without migration, the goals are executed correctly and I can activate the Developer Mode, but the debugging has no effect; moreover, in the console, only a trace similar to this one appears:
[image]